# After Effects clone composition change assets?

Tags: composition, after-effects

I am new to AE and I want to duplicate a composition but the assets belonging to it I want to replace with new footage can I do this?

I have gone into the project window and duplicated the composition however it also references the same images. I want to keep the same animation belonging to the footage but simply replace the image.

Thanks in advance, DS.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a programming question.
But you can open a comp and then replace a layer selecting it and the holding ALT while dragging a different footage item (from the project window) on top of it .